# "Failed to load resource: net::ERR_FILE_NOT_FOUND " while creating chrome extension

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension

I want to import and use a function in **popup.js** from **fetchTabDataFunc** , but when I try to do so it shows me the error "Failed to load resource: net::ERR_FILE_NOT_FOUND"

**Things that I have done.**

In my html file (popup.html) I have added `<script src="popup.js" type ="module" ></script>`, in which I have added the attribute *type="module"*  to connect the js file with html file.

My manifest.json file

```
 {
  "name": "club-tab",
  "description": "to club active tabs",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "manifest_version": 3,
  "background": {
    "service_worker": "background.js",
    "type": "module"
  },
  "action": {
    "default_popup": "popup.html"
  },
  "permissions": ["tabs", "activeTab"],
  "host_permissions": ["http://*/*", "https://*/*"]
}
```

My folder structure is as follow:
[image: file structure]

fetchTabDataFunc file code

```
const  fetchTabDataFunc = async ( linkContainer)=>{
    try {
        console.log("i am in fetch func")
        const response = await chrome.tabs.query({});
        tabData = await response
        const ul = document.createElement('ul');
        linkContainer.appendChild(ul)
        if (tabData) {
            ul.innerHTML = tabData.map((tab) => {
                return `<li>${tab.title}</li>`
            }).join('')
        }
        console.log(tabData);
    } catch (error) {
        console.log(error);
    }
}

export default fetchTabDataFunc
```

popup.js file code

```
import fetchTabDataFunc from "./fetchTabDataFunc";
const btn = document.querySelector('.btn');
const linkContainer = document.querySelector('.link-container');

let tabData = [];


btn.addEventListener('click', async () => {
    console.log("i am in popup.js btn")

    if (tabData.length == 0) {
        fetchTabDataFunc(linkContainer)
    }

});
```

Comment: To use native ES modules you need to specify `.js` extension in the `import` file name explicitly.

Comment: @wOxxOm thanks it worked. In react we don't need to specify the extension so I though it would be some for js too.